# Compare date components Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have a task where I have to read the file once a day.

1)Label with text and the date blank.

2)When the user first goes to view.  I need to show the text, save it and the date when it was followed

3)Leave it all on the screen all day.

4)When the next day comes. Compare the saved date with the current date.

5)If the current date is greater than the stored date. then read the file again, show the text and the date when this is done and save
(While there is this. The text changes every time you enter the application.
A saved date = 0,)

```
// compare oderDate and currentDate 
func showTextToDay() {
    let newDatePredict = Date()
    let olderDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: dateUser) as! Date // THIS PROBLEM
    let order = Calendar.current.compare(olderDate, to: newDatePredict, toGranularity: .day)
    switch order {
    case .orderedDescending:
        print("DESCENDING")
    case .orderedAscending:
        readFilePrediction() //read again file bcs new day
        print("ASCENDING")
    case .orderedSame:
        print("SAME")      
    }
}
func readFilePrediction() {
    //some code
}
// save olderDate Func
func saveDatePredictFunc() {  
    let oldDatePredict = Date()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(oldDatePredict, forKey: dateUser)
    let dateLabel = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: dateUser) as! Date
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    toDateOutlet.text = df.string(from: dateLabel)
    defaults.set(toDateOutlet.text, forKey: dateUser)
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: let olderDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: dateUser) as! Date //error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: avoid force unwrap, store old date in string format and after accessing it from user default convert it into Date after that perform compare

Comment: @sujitnachan in the function where I save the date and show it in Label, I translate it into a string and then return it as a date to a variable (let olderDate) and get it from the key

Comment: `defaults.set(toDateOutlet.text, forKey: dateUser)` will save an optional `String?` not a `Date`. When you try to force cast it from `String` to `Date` it crashes

Comment: @leoDabus Yes thank you. You have given good advice. I converted the string back to date. But now for some reason it shows that it is empty. I will think how to do it right    
   ( let order = Calendar.current.compare(olderDate!, to: newDatePredict, toGranularity: .day)) -Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: don't force unwrap your values. use `if let` to unwrap it. try reseting your UserDefaults `UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "")`

Comment: @leodabus I think I understand what the problem is. The function where I only have to save the date will be executed only after comparison. You need to somehow save the date separately and then compare

Comment: That was my first comment. You need save it before reading it. You can provide a default value using the nil coalescing operator `?? defaultDate`.

Comment: @leodabus Please tell me how I could save the date before the comparison. After all, I will have to save it when I read the file.

Comment: you can provide it at the time of the comparison as well if you don't force unwrap it `olderDate ?? defaultDate`. default date can be `Date()`, `.distantPast` or `.distantFuture`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check also if a date a available at all.

The guard statement represents a NOR expression. `readFilePrediction` will be executed if the date does **NOT** exist **OR** the date comparison is ascending.

```
func showTextToDay()
{
    guard let olderDate = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: dateUser) as? Date,
        Calendar.current.compare(olderDate, to: Date(), toGranularity: .day) != .orderedAscending else {
            readFilePrediction()
            saveDatePredictFunc()
            return
    }
}
```

And reading the data right after saving it to `UserDefaults` (`dateLabel`) is very bad practice. You got the value. And delete also the line to save the string representation of the date. The line breaks the ability to read the value as `Date`.

```
func saveDatePredictFunc()
{   
    let oldDatePredict = Date()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(oldDatePredict, forKey: dateUser)
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
    toDateOutlet.text = df.string(from: oldDatePredict)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code in my project. But now my date does not show in toDateOutlet and the text does not change when I change the days in the calendar

Comment: If `readFilePrediction` is empty like in the question of course nothing is displayed.

Comment: I need to save the date every time I read the file. And this date appears in Label. I don’t know how to combine this with your code (

Comment: Just call `saveDatePredictFunc` right after `readFilePrediction`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Everything works, thank you. But the date is not yet displayed in Label. Although stored in UserDefaults

Comment: Check if the outlet is connected. According to the code the line `toDateOutlet.text = df...` is supposed to show the current date

Comment: Yes, I checked and even reconnected. So far it still doesn't show anything

Comment: I reconnected, and when I brought to the console then the value of nil.How can it be nil if the dates are compared

Comment: Consider that `saveDatePredictFunc` is only called if the conditions are met. You might add code in `showTextToDay` which displays something if the `guard` statement evaluates to `true`